# What does "override implicit" mean?

Tags: scala

I am looking at a piece of code that says

```
case class MyClass(override implicit val x : SomeClass) extends SomeOtherClass(...) {
    ...
}
```

What does `override implicit` mean in this context, and what can I do if I want to produce an instance of `MyClass` with explicit parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that `SomeOtherClass` has a field `x` of type `SomeClass` that will be overriden by the `x` you pass in the constructor of `MyClass`.

The `implicit` will make the `x` argument for my class `implicit` and allow the following code:

```
implicit val someInt = 5
val a = new MyClass
val b = new MyClass()
val c = MyClass() // as it it a case class
```

If you want to produce an instance of `MyClass` with explicit parameters, you can pass them explicitly like this:

```
val a = new MyClass()(42)
```

(Examples assume that `SomeClass` is an `Int`, for simplicity)

To clarify: the `implicit` and `override` keywords here are unrelated.

Comment: Actually, there's more to say. I think it's a bug. `trait X { def i: Int }` then `case class C(override implicit val i: Int, j: Int) extends X` should not make `j` and perhaps not `i` an implicit parameter, since implicit is a LocalModifier here and not the leading token in last ClassParamClauses. But maybe this is just a compromise in the syntax. `class Y(private implicit val i: Int, val j: Int)` makes it more obvious that the implicit looks wrongly scoped. `j` is not private.

Comment: `implicit` always applies to whole parameter list and this parameter list has to be last one, that is the rule, but maybe not very intuitive looking at your example

Comment: It special-cases the modifier on the first param. `class Y(private val i: Int, implicit val j: Int)`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but putting implicit on the second argument as you did doesn't allow to create object unless you put both `i` and `j` explicitly

Comment: Exactly. I'm suggesting `implicit` as a modifier should not make an implicit param list; it should work the same in both my examples. You should have to say `class Y(implicit override val i: Int)` for that behavior; it's a different production in the grammar.